# CAML- WebService Sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, caml

Hello stackoverflow community

I got a load of help from this forum. Though this time i couldn't find.

I Made an ASP.NET application and I try to use a SharePoint WebService to get some Items of a List.

So far i succeed in getting the whole list using CAML request, but i have to select the items between 2 given dates

I found a lot of help around this and I'm using this method to format the ISO 8601 date string :

```
private string FormatDateForCAML(DateTime theDate)
{
    string result = theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    return result;
}
```

And here is the CAML request building :

```
System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
query.InnerXml = 
        "<Where>"+
            "<And>"+
              "<Geq>"+
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"startdate\" />"+
                  "<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">" + theStart + "</Value>" +
              "</Geq>"+
              "<Lt>" +
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"enddate\" />" +
                  "<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">" + theEnd+ "</Value>" +
              "</Lt>" +
            "</And>"+
        "</Where>";
```

I don't have any error return by this query :

```
System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = listService.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);
```

But the list returned is null though it shoudn't

Thanks for any help.

EDIT : I finally succeed, problem came from a wrong request here is the proper version

```
System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
query.InnerXml = 
        "<Where>"+
            "<And>"+
              "<Geq>"+
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"startdate\" />"+
                  "<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">" + theStart + "</Value>" +
              "</Geq>"+
              "<Lt>" +
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"startdate\" />" +
                  "<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">" + theEnd+ "</Value>" +
              "</Lt>" +
            "</And>"+
        "</Where>";
```

Thanks to Roqz I Used the CAML viewer,and I could get the problem : I had to compare the start date only !

Thank you both for help :)

Comment: have you tried building your request with a tool like U2U CAML Query Builder to check if it runs this way? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458008/CAML-Query-Builder

Comment: Thx for reply. I Will try to use it this afternoon and bring back result here. Though I Tried to add <Query></Query> around the <Where> element, and it now bring the whole List, ignoring my "where" clause

Comment: Depending on the version of SharePoint you can also use RSS feeds for lists if at all querying using CAML + Native Web Services does not workout.

Comment: @Roqz : I Tried to Download CAML-QUery-Builder, but the link seems dead. 
Himanshu : The Sharepoint version is 2007. Regarding RSS Feeds I do have to do some research. I will come back here as soon as i know more about it. 
(since i am working on several project, it may take a while but i will be back here for feed back, and try any suggestion)

Comment: @Roqz : I used another tool named : StramitCAML Viewer. Apparently, my CAML request doesn't work. The format of the where clause seems to not be proper.... So my goal is now to succeed in Doing a good CAML request : Here is what is played at the moment.
    <Query>
 <Where>
  <And>
   <Geq>
    <FieldRef Name="startdate" />
    <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="True">2013-04-01T00:00:00</Value>
   </Geq>
   <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name="enddate" />
    <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="True">2013-05-01T00:00:00</Value>
   </Lt>
  </And>
 </Where>
    </Query>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CAML Builder Tool a Query similar to yours does return the result it should.
Query looks like:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-04-01T19:35:49Z</Value>                 
          </Geq>
          <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-05-24T19:36:46Z</Value>
          </Lt>
        </And>
     </Where>
</Query>
```

But as I remember, if you want to use this query in code than you do not need the surrounding  tags. 
Have you checked that your date format is correct? in your example I can't see the "Z" at the end.

Comment: Problem solved thanks a lot !! I edited the original post. I just add a problem with the date filed i had to compare only startdate, and not startdate + enddate. Newb me ! Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your CAML query in a console application using full SharePoint object model with any clause you want like you want to filter on dates. If your CAML works in full SharePoint object model it should ideally work as well when you try to fetch data using SharePoint Native Web Services.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I don't have Sharepoint server installed on my computer. I may do something wrong. I am totally new to Sharepoint. I don't have acces to the Sharepoint server too. So can I still use Sharepoint object model ?

Comment: If you don't have access to SharePoint server the only way to use SharePoint object is via remoting which you are already doing when you use SharePoint Native Web Services, though the services do not expose all SP object model capabilities. Another way could be to use RSS feeds for your lists provided it suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that this method :

```
private string FormatDateForCAML(DateTime theDate)
{
    string result = theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    return result;
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
private string FormatDateForCAML(DateTime theDate)
{
    string result = theDate.ToString("s");
    return result;
}
```

date.ToString("s") return a ISO.8601 date format string.